# Problem of permutations and combinations.

Tags: permutations, combinations

Two players A and B are playing an asymmetrical game.There are n points on the game board.Each turn player A targets a pair of points and player B says whether those two points are connected or unconnected.A can target each pair only once and the game ends when all pairs have been targeted. Player B wins iff a point is connected with all other points on the very last turn while player A wins if any point is connected with all other points on any turn but the very last one OR if no point is connected to all other points after the last turn.For what values of n does either player have a winning strategy?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  The usual start for something like this would be to solve it explicitly for small $n$ and see if any patterns emerge.

Comment: From where have you got this problem ? And please edit to show your efforts, and where you are stuck, which is a must for people to aid you.

Comment: I tried it but not getting approach. How to start the problem. I have invested a lot of time on it.

Comment: I am a school student in India preparing for IIT JEE

Comment: A friend of mine sent it to me , so I don't know the source exactly. I'll update if I get to know